# Only the SelectedRows on Datagrid will be affected

Tags: c#, winforms, linq

I have a datagridview  for my table Identification with a Status on the last column.

So let's assume I selected 5 rows out of 10 rows on my datagridview.

What I'm trying to do is that when I clicked a button, only the selected rows will be affected and their status will be change.

I have tried this code and other codes and none of them seems to work. I'm new in c#, so is there anybody that could help me?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int count = dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count;
        for (int i = count-1; i >=0; i--)
        {

            if (i == dataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count)
            {
                Identification it = new Identification();
                it.Status = "ACTIVE";
                Repository.Identification_UpdateStatus(it);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to loop through
dataGridView1.SelectedRows to get each DataGridViewRow object
Code:

```
foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
{
   // implement your logic here
   // update selected rows by making changes to 'row'  object
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The PROPER way to do this would be to use DataBinding. Since you're using domain objects such as 'Identification' it would be a proper fit here.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    //Your form
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Wrap your objects in a binding list before setting it as the 
        //datasource of your datagrid
        BindingList<Identification> ids = new BindingList<Identification>
        {
            new Identification() { status="NEW"  },
             new Identification() { status="NEW"  },
              new Identification() {status="NEW"  },
        };
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ids;
    }

    private void btnChangeStatus_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   //Where the actual status changing takes place
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.SelectedRows)
        {
            var identifaction = row.DataBoundItem as Identification;
            identifaction.status = "VERIFIED";
        }

    }
    //Model: Class that carries your data
    class Identification: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _status;
        public string status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set
            {
                _status = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("status");
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }

    }    

}
```